# Syntax highlighting editor with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently working on an PyQt5 based application I could use an (embedded) editor for which provides some syntax highlighting for YAML (and maybe JSON).

I expected Qt to have some built-in capabilities for this but all I found were some discussions and some hand-made implementations like [this one](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Python%20syntax%20highlighting).

Isn't there a simple way to activate syntax highlighting on an existing widget? Or maybe a compact 3rd party widget I might use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`QsciScintilla`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciScintilla.html) class with the [`QsciLexerJSON`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciLexerJSON.html) and [`QsciLexerYAML`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciLexerYAML.html) lexers of the [QScintilla](https://pypi.org/project/QScintilla/) module.

```py
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, Qsci

JSON = """
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
"""

YAML = """
--- !clarkevans.com/^invoice
invoice: 34843
date   : 2001-01-23
bill-to: &id001
    given  : Chris
    family : Dumars
    address:
        lines: |
            458 Walkman Dr.
            Suite #292
        city    : Royal Oak
        state   : MI
        postal  : 48046
ship-to: *id001
product:
    - sku         : BL394D
      quantity    : 4
      description : Basketball
      price       : 450.00
    - sku         : BL4438H
      quantity    : 1
      description : Super Hoop
      price       : 2392.00
tax  : 251.42
total: 4443.52
comments: >
    Late afternoon is best.
    Backup contact is Nancy
    Billsmer @ 338-4338.
"""


class JSONEditor(Qsci.QsciScintilla):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setLexer(Qsci.QsciLexerJSON(self))
        self.setText(JSON)


class YAMLEditor(Qsci.QsciScintilla):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setLexer(Qsci.QsciLexerYAML(self))
        self.setText(YAML)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(JSONEditor())
    lay.addWidget(YAMLEditor())
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Would have given more +1s if possible just because the code is so pythonic